# Can't connect to local Postgres in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, connection, localhost

This seems like it should be a very basic problem to fix, but it's driven me to the brink of madness and cost me days of work.

I'm trying to run Java integration tests locally but they're failing due to a PSQLException in connecting. In my terminal, I'm pinging `localhost` fine and I can successfully telnet to 5432. I can get to the local DB using Postico as well. To try to get at this problem, I'm trying to configure a database within IDEA. It's pretty elementary. The URL is `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres` and all the other settings match my successful Postico configuration. I haven't changed anything in the Drivers tab; the PostgreSQL driver is 42.6.0, the latest stable. (I tried a few older ones, including all the way back to 9.x; no dice.) We use PostgreSQL 13.10.

This is especially puzzling because everything was fine last week, then I opened up my computer on Monday and everything was broken. I have 2023.2 on my Mac, but this issue was happening before that. I even completely uninstalled IDEA and deleted all of the JetBrains/IDEA settings from `~/Library` to start again, but no change. Hoping to find some insights here, as my team and I are completely out of ideas short of an exorcism. Thanks.

Additional info added from comments:

`/etc/hosts`, excluding comments, is:

```bash
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

There isn't much clueful in the logging. I see only "The connection attempt failed" in the UI. That message is associated with `DatabaseConnectionEstablisher`, ID 08001.

`sudo lsof -i :5432` yields:

```bash
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 535  [me]  223u  IPv6 0xdc13b7dc139e8629      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Any customizations to your `/etc/hosts`? Does localhost resolve to 127.0.0.1? Does it help if you add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE?

Comment: My `/etc/hosts`, excluding comments, says `127.0.0.1 localhost / 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost / ::1 localhost`. (Sorry; can't figure out how to get that to display nicely, so I used slashes to separate lines and removed extra whitespace.)

The `-Djava` line had no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: What errors do you get in the IDE? Any exceptions in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: In the UI I get only "The connection attempt failed." There doesn't seem to be anything clueful in the log; the only thing I see is that same message from `DatabaseConnectionEstablisher` with the ID 08001.

Comment: What does `sudo lsof -i :5432` show?

Comment: With the user redacted: `COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 535 [me]  223u  IPv6 0xdc13b7dc139e8629      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)`

Comment: Post those additional facts as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: Can do, and in fact done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `lsof` output the database server is listening on IPv6 interface instead of IPv4.

To force IntelliJ IDEA/DataGrip use IPv6 you can add the following in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```

You may also need to add the same in the data source Advanced settings, **VM options** field and in the VM Options for your tests / Java apps.

Comment: We still don't know why on Earth this suddenly started failing when I didn't touch it at all; the best hypothesis we've got is that NordLayer messed with the networking stack somehow.

Comment: One additional note: I found it better to put these lines only in the JUnit configuration template. When they were in the overall Custom VM Options, my Maven syncing broke; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77125764/12027515