# "Connection refused to host ::1" when reloading Maven in IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, connection-refused

This is IDEA 2023.2.2 Ultimate, though I just updated today and this was certainly a problem before. M1 Macbook on Ventura 13.5.2.

Whenever I open IDEA, I'm presented with this in the Sync tab, with no further trace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: ::1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I more or less ignored this until today, when I needed to introduce a new Maven dependency and found myself completely unable to do so. I added a new `<dependency>` entry to `pom.xml`, but there is no way to get IDEA to accept it. Clicking Reload All Maven Projects immediately gives me the above error every time. The new dependency never appears in External Libraries and it's unavailable when developing.

Strangely, running `mvn dependency:tree` in my terminal, whether outside or within IDEA, seems to work fine. I see the new one in the list. But in neither case does it have any effect in IDEA.

My teammate has the same Maven configuration (which I've never touched) and he was able to get the new dependency just fine after checking out my branch, so I'm kind of going nuts here. Being on or off VPN doesn't seem to have any effect.

`/etc/hosts`, if that matters, is

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

`/Users/tyler/.m2/settings.xml` doesn't exist for me. The same is true for my teammates, though.

Here are some relevant Maven settings:

[image: Screenshot of my IDEA Maven settings]

[image: Screenshot of more IDEA Maven settings]

Comment: What’s in the `/Users/tyler/.m2/settings.xml` file? My guess would be that there is a mirror or proxy configured there. You might be able to get a more detailed error by running Maven on the command line with `-e`, such as `mvn -e clean install`

Comment: are there non-https mirrors/repositories configured?

Comment: The `settings.xml` file doesn't exist for me, but the same is true for my teammates, who are having no problems. Updated my question to include that, as well as noting that `mvn dependency:tree` works fine when running it in a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA runs Maven Daemon as a separate process, which it communicates with using RMI/loopback.
Judging from the error message you are getting, something is preventing IDEA from talking to Maven Daemon.

This is most often caused by firewalls and/or security solutions.
See also:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014262940-Unable-to-import-Maven-project-import-fails-with-error-Cannot-reconnect

Note that your computer seems to be using IPv6, which may make this more complicated.
For instance, IPv6 may have a different set of firewall/routing rules. You can try switching to IPv4 to see if that helps.

Comment: Interesting. I made it that thanks to the previous bizarre problem I had with IDEA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76838153/cant-connect-to-local-postgres-in-intellij-idea/76838451#76838451

Comment: Well look at that. I removed the two VM Options lines suggested in the above-linked answer and it works again. Of course, now it appears I have to choose between keeping Maven updated and running integration tests, but that's a different problem. Thanks!